# How to convert my database ID number to text before CSV export?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm hoping this is an easy one. How can I convert the ID number in mysql database into text before exporting it into a csv file?

Here is my code that exports my data:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=csv_file.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    fputcsv($output, $field);
}
```

I can export the data from the database into a csv just fine but is there a way to convert the ID number to text so that excel doesn't strip away the leading zeros?

Thanks!

Comment: Either surround it with single quotes or [cast it to text](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting).

Comment: How come there's leading zeros in your IDs?

Comment: My client wants to export the file as a csv with 4 zeros in front of the ID number so that they can import it into their own systems....go figure!

Comment: @m02ph3u5 It must have been defined with ZEROFILL option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV doesn't hold field type information, so you need to format and define type of your data while **importing** in Excel, not in the process of exporting.

Comment: @stalwil In Excel - importing tool has options to select types of fields (columns), you can load ID's as numbers and then give them formating similar to your needs (like add leading 0's etc), or actually change it to string.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap them with quotes?

Assuming your IDs are at index 0:

```
while ($field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $field[0] = '"' . field[0] . '"';
    fputcsv($output, $field);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that was going to work...but it's still displaying on the exported csv file as 1, 2, 3...and in my database I have 00001, 00002, 00003.

Comment: Works fine for me; have you checked that you're actually getting '00001' etc.? And are you looking at the plain csv contents (with a text editor or cat)?

Comment: Yes...when I open the csv file in a text editor I see the Zeros...but when it's opened in excel the Zeros fall off.

Comment: Then it's not a php issue but rather an excel issue. See madneon's answer.